# Calendar popup field get a default value. How to avoid this?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have all necessary module to add "Calendar popup" fields to my nodes.

When creating a new node this field is populated with the current date. Since this field is not mandatory I need it empty by default.

I can´t figure out how to accomplish this.  Please help.

I upload a capture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the date field in your Content Type.  There should be a `MORE SETTINGS AND VALUES` accordion that drops down to reveal more options including `DEFAULT VALUES`.  Set the default value to *No Default Value*.  You probably have it set to *Now*.